# Performance Optimising a CMS System

Tags: performance, optimization, content-management-system

I'm currently building a high performance CMS system and am trying to find the most efficient way of retrieving and storing documents.

So I have a simple database driven CMS database where articles are stored within the database and each article request involves a database lookup.

I was considering storing the content of the CMS page as a physical file (rather than in the database) and writing a tool that scans the database and creates a HTACCESS file (essentially bypassing both PHP and MySQL).

Are there any disadvantages to this, or is there a more efficient method that I am missing?

Because it needs to be portable I can't rely on any outside technology such as memcache or varnish but it could be an option for certain client installations.

Comment: This is really a broad question, and there are lots of aspects of it, and it depends on all of your use-cases.  Sometimes you need multiple data-stores (a DB of record, a search index, a denormalized index).  Each of which has different potential solutions, with pros and cons.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, I was just after the most processor efficient way of serving up CMS content. As my data is all static this connects the url directly to the content without requiring PHP or MySQL. My main goal is very high read throughput and using as little resources as possible. I've never seen this concept used by any project so I was wondering if there was any caveats to this technique I should be aware of, or any better performing solutions.

Comment: The read performance is probably fine. It's the maintenance that'll be a pain. Making sure to write the files you want, updating everywhere. Makes it impossible to have a dynamic site basically.

Comment: well what i was planning on doing was having the site regenerate the htaccess file each time an update is made to a content file. Like I said the write frequency is fairly low compared with the read frequency. My main goal was to cut out as much of the overhead as possible. I know that htaccess is fast but if you had a large number of records say 50,000 would it be faster than doing a database lookup for each request?

Comment: I work on a CMS professionally that serves many business units within the company I work for.  We have hundreds of thousands of articles, videos, galleries, and more.  The sites are all highly dynamic.  We use a database, not files.  Could it be faster to use files? Maybe, but it would be a lot harder to maintain.  Also, when you scale up writes, rebuilding the files every time will start to have problems.  That was our old system (15 years ago).  Our new system doesn't cache pages to disk.